# Find out the M.2 SSD connector of my laptop supported datatypes

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, laptop, ssd

The M.2 SSD connector slot of my laptop is currently empty. I am planning to add a M.2 SSD. But before, I need to find out what type of M.2 SSD does my connector support.

I typed `wmic /namespace:\\root\microsoft\windows\storage path msft_disk get Model,BusType` on the command prompt, but that seems to get model and bus type of the current 2.5" SSD connected to my laptop.

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 - i7559 gaming laptop. Here is a picture
[image]

Comment: What model is your laptop? I mean which Inspiron model number

Comment: [This](https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/How-do-I-know-if-Dell-inspiron-7559-supports-either-M-2-NVMe-or/td-p/6033220) and [this](https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/Will-NVMe-M-2-work-in-Inspiron-15-7559/td-p/7439467) might be helpful.  You should [edit] your question to provide some additional information about your device.

Comment: Hi, what additional info you need? And thanks for the link. It helps. Is there a more formal way, like a command code that I can run to check?